# SQL code unable to run for 2 student value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
;with SGPA
as (select stud.StudentID,
           stud.StudentName,
           studsc.Semester,
           SUM(course.Credit) as 'CreditSemester',
           SUM(course.Credit * wght.[Weight]) / SUM(course.Credit) as 'SemesterGPA'
    from Student as stud
        inner join StudentScore as studsc
            on stud.StudentID = studsc.StudentID
        inner join Course as course
            on studsc.CourseID = course.CourseID
        inner join [Weight] as wght
            on studsc.Grade = wght.Grade
    group by stud.StudentID,
             stud.StudentName,
             studsc.Semester
   )



select *, 
(select SUM(CreditSemester) from SGPA i) as 'CreditCumulative', 
(select AVG(SemesterGPA) from SGPA i) as 'CumulativeGPA'

from SGPA o
```

When I try 2 different student their CreditCumulative and CumulativeGPA fused

example:
SYLYIA KUYEPUTRA, 20192, CreditSemester 13, SemesterGPA 3,36
JUAN KANAM, 20192,CreditSemester 20, SemesterGPA 3,68

their CreditCumulative became 33 and cumulativeGPA 3,52

All table data :
https://ibb.co/pPZWQYf

Comment: show your sample data.. it could be one of the joins that is dropping them out for example..

Comment: https://ibb.co/pPZWQYf
there are all the tables with data I have created

Comment: I hope these are not people's real names and scores!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select from your Sub query, you need to filter to the StudentIds

```
select *, 
(select SUM(CreditSemester) from SGPA i WHERE i.StudentId = o.StudentId) as 'CreditCumulative', 
(select AVG(SemesterGPA) from SGPA i WHERE i.StudentId = o.StudentId) as 'CumulativeGPA'

from SGPA o
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)